# No items showing up in menu

Tags: c++, gtk, gtkmm

I'm currently haveing a bit of a problem with a Gtk popup menu.

I have a MenuButton set with a Menu which has a MenuItem.

When clicked the Menu pops up but only a tiny bit of it, as if there are no items and doesn't show the Preferences item.

Is there a function I'm not calling or is the MenuItem not being added. As I took a look at program in the Inspector and it doesn't show a Menu anywhere.

I don't want to use the Gtk Builder with Glade just to create a popup menu.

Not sure if this is needed but this is under Msys2 with Gtk 3.22.

```
#include <gtkmm.h>

class WindowTest : public Gtk::Window {
public:
    WindowTest() {
        set_titlebar(mHeaderBarApp);

        mBoxContainer.set_orientation(Gtk::Orientation::ORIENTATION_VERTICAL);

        mBoxContainer.pack_start(mHeaderBarApp, false, true, 0);

        mHeaderBarApp.set_show_close_button(true);

        mHeaderBarApp.pack_end(mMenuButtonApp);

        mMenuButtonApp.set_image(mImageApp);
        mImageApp.set_from_icon_name("open-menu-symbolic", Gtk::BuiltinIconSize::ICON_SIZE_BUTTON);

        mMenuButtonApp.set_popup(mMenuApp);
        mMenuApp.append(mMenuItemPreferences);
        mMenuItemPreferences.set_label("Preferences");

        add(mBoxContainer);

        show_all_children();
    };

    virtual ~WindowTest() {};

protected:
    Gtk::Box mBoxContainer;
    Gtk::HeaderBar mHeaderBarApp;
    Gtk::MenuButton mMenuButtonApp;
    Gtk::Image mImageApp;
    Gtk::Menu mMenuApp;
    Gtk::MenuItem mMenuItemPreferences;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Application> app = Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv, "com.site.test");

    WindowTest windowTest;
    windowTest.set_default_size(600, 400);

    return app->run(windowTest);
}
```